JDBC returns nothing
I am building an API with Spring and JDBC. I now ran into a problem where the JDBC query would not return anything, even though the same query in SQL Developer returns data.
This is my method in java:
public Standardtexte getStandardtexte(String kurztext)
{
    Standardtexte standardtexte = new Standardtexte();
    standardtexte.kurztext = kurztext;
    standardtexte.schluessel = jdbc.query("select schluessel, langtext from hb_standardtexte where kurztext = ?", (rs, rowNum) -> {
        Schluessel s = new Schluessel();
        s.schluessel = StringUtils.trimToEmpty(rs.getString(1));
        s.langtext = StringUtils.trimToEmpty(rs.getString(2));
        return s;
    }, kurztext);
    return standardtexte;
}

I am trying this request in Postman: localhost:8080/standardtexte?kurztext=KOELUNG but getting no useful result:
{
    "kurztext": "KOELUNG",
    "schluessel": []
}

When I try the same query in SQL Developer:
select schluessel, langtext from hb_standardtexte where kurztext = 'KOELUNG';

I get this result: Result table image
Can someone help me / explain why this is happening?
I also have tried it with other parameters for kurztext: The weird thing: other parameters work.

Are you sure you're connected to the same schema in the same database - or at least viewing exactly the same table? And if so, has the data for KOELUNG just been inserted in the same SQL Developer session and has not yet been committed?

The query and the code seems to be correct ( List query(String var1, RowMapper var2, Object... var3)). Alex Poole might be correct. I just want to add one thing, can it be because rs.getString(1) and rs.getString(2), how about if we try rs.getString("schluessel") and rs.getString("langtext")?

What is the output of select DUMP(kurztext), DUMP('KOELUNG') from hb_standardtexte where kurztext = 'KOELUNG';? Do the values match or is there trailing whitespace?

What is the CREATE TABLE statement for the hb_standardtexte table?

Summary: Don't use the CHAR data-type for variable-length strings. Use VARCHAR2.

If the table is:
CREATE TABLE hb_standardtexte (
  kurztext CHAR(10)
);

With the data:
INSERT INTO hb_standardtexte (kurztext) VALUES ('KOELUNG')

Then when you use:
select kurztext
from   hb_standardtexte
where  kurztext = 'KOELUNG';

The output is:



KURZTEXT




KOELUNG



The Oracle Literal documentation states:

Text literals have properties of both the CHAR and VARCHAR2 data types:

Within expressions and conditions, Oracle treats text literals as though they have the data type CHAR by comparing them using blank-padded comparison semantics.


The Data Type Comparison Rules state:

Blank-Padded and Nonpadded Comparison Semantics
With blank-padded semantics, if the two values have different lengths, then Oracle first adds blanks to the end of the shorter one so their lengths are equal. Oracle then compares the values character by character up to the first character that differs. The value with the greater character in the first differing position is considered greater. If two values have no differing characters, then they are considered equal. This rule means that two values are equal if they differ only in the number of trailing blanks. Oracle uses blank-padded comparison semantics only when both values in the comparison are either expressions of data type CHAR, NCHAR, text literals, or values returned by the USER function.
With nonpadded semantics, Oracle compares two values character by character up to the first character that differs. The value with the greater character in that position is considered greater. If two values of different length are identical up to the end of the shorter one, then the longer value is considered greater. If two values of equal length have no differing characters, then the values are considered equal. Oracle uses nonpadded comparison semantics whenever one or both values in the comparison have the data type VARCHAR2 or NVARCHAR2.

If you are passing the value such that it has a VARCHAR2 data-type. For example, this can be forced in SQL by using CAST:
select kurztext
from   hb_standardtexte
where  kurztext = CAST('KOELUNG' AS VARCHAR2(10));

Then blank-padded comparison semantics are not used and the query outputs zero rows.
You are likely to find that Java is passing the value as a VARCHAR2 and not as a CHAR.

The normal solution is:

Fix your table and not to use CHAR data-types and always use VARCHAR2 for the column and remove any padding.
ALTER TABLE hb_standardtexte MODIFY kurztext VARCHAR2(10);

UPDATE hb_standardtexte
SET   kurztext = RTRIM(kurztext)
WHERE kurztext LIKE '% ';

Then your query should work.

If you must use CHAR then pad the string with whitespace to the correct length (i.e. pass the string "KOELUNG   ", assuming the column is 10 characters long, and not "KOELUNG").


fiddle

thank you, padding the String with trailing whitespaces solved my problem!

Make sure you COMMIT your data.
In Oracle, if you do not COMMIT then only the session where the the data was created can see the uncommitted data and other sessions, even those belonging to the same user, will never see that uncommitted data.
For example, the behaviour can be explained:

If you create the data in SQL Developer but do not COMMIT the data or close the session.
Then if you query the data from Java then it will connect to the database and create a new session (even if you connect as the same user) and then you will never see the uncommitted data.
But if you go back to the open session in SQL Developer then you will see the data exists in its uncommitted form in that session.
To see it in other sessions, COMMIT the data in SQL Developer.


Yeah all the data is commited. As I said the weird thing is that it works with other parameters... just "KOELUNG" does not work for some reason

Run this to check, if your SQL is correct
select schluessel, langtext from hb_standardtexte where kurztext = 'KOELUNG';


Isn't this exactly the same as what the OP said he already tried and shown to work?

Also, this can return results in SQL since 'KOELUNG' is a text literal and compared as if it has a CHAR data type but passing the Java string "KOELUNG" to a bind variable ? in the query (instead of using a literal) can return zero rows because the the bind variable is being treated as a VARCHAR2 (and not as a CHAR) and different comparison semantics are being used by the database.

After that, it’s verified the charset and collation? Is this which consistent with the env? I started debbug, sorry. Have a binding issue
